# Using the JH Labs Java Image Library With Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am trying to use different methods of [JH Labs](http://www.jhlabs.com/) Free Java Library with ColdFusion. I am having a bit of a hard time sorting this Method. I am using Javaloader by Mark to dynamically handle the JAR file.

Now here is the following code:

```
<cfscript>
imgscalrPath = ExpandPath("filters/Filters.jar");
loader = new javaloader.javaLoader([imgscalrPath]);
Scalr = loader.create( "com.jhlabs.image.BoxBlurFilter" );
WriteDump(Scalr);
sourceImage =   ImageNew("#UploadDir2#/#form.uploadfile#");
</cfscript>
<cfimage
action="writeToBrowser"
source="#sourceImage#"
format="jpg"
/>
<cfscript>
smallerImage    =   Scalr.blur([1,2],[2,3],20,5,3);
ImageWrite(smallerImage,"#UploadDir2#/getoff.jpg");
</cfscript>
```

I dumped the `Scalr` and it gave me the following image which shows the method, but when I try to use the method, ColdFusion says the method is not found.

I am not sure what is going on here. Can any expert throw some advice?

[http://i.share.pho.to/f973fa61_o.gif](http://share.pho.to/5x2kW/eh/original)

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that the `blur` function has returntype void.  So trying to assign it to your `smallerImage` variable is pointless.

Comment: I can't see where you are passing your image in to the scalr object - perhaps that's why you can't successfully call the method.

Comment: @duncan: Even if i trying using the `filter` function, it gives me same error. @Antony: I did tried passing the name of the image sourceImage but i gave me a different error of **cfimage can only accept base64, blob type images**

Comment: @odd_even_algorithm - update your question to include that code. Sounds like you should fix that problem first

Comment: @odd_even_algorithm you shouldn't get an error from `cfimage` when you load your image into the `scalr` object. Post all the code that initiates `scalr` and show where you load the uploaded image into it. There's not much in the way of documentation that i can see on the jhlabs site - are you sure the jar can be used the way you intend?

Comment: @Antony, I will post Code later, I am away from my PC as of now, so i will do by evening

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, did you try the usual suggestion of using `javacast` on the parameters?

Comment: Hi Leigh, No I did not used `Javacast`, well with `JavaCast`, I do not know how to use it. Any simple example of doing this could be great..

Comment: The documentation on [JavaCast](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbe.html) contains a bunch of examples.